# Reduce an array of objects based on custom logic

Tags: javascript, lodash, reduce, overlap

I trying to reduce an an array of object by merging the keys between them based on a logic.

**Explanation**

I'd like to reduce the following arrays (see below) by their keys :

1. `lines` : Merge numbers ranges which are in common between them (ex: [1,2] + [3,2] = [1,2,3])
2. `dates`: Merges arrays dates associated with the `lines` keys

All dupplicate arrays and/or keys should be deleted.

**Examples :**

Input **exemple A** :

```js
const errors = [
  {
    "lines": [1, 2],
    "dates": [["2020-12-12","2020-12-19"], ["2020-12-13","2020-12-25"]]
  },
  {
    "lines": [1, 3],
    "dates": [["2020-12-12","2020-12-19"], ["2020-12-15","2020-12-17"]]
  },
  {
    "lines": [2, 3],
    "dates": [["2020-12-13","2020-12-25"], ["2020-12-15","2020-12-17"]]
  },
  {
    "lines": [3, 2],
    "dates": [["2020-12-15","2020-12-17"], ["2020-12-13","2020-12-25"]]
  }
]
```

Output **example A** :

```js
const expected = [{
  lines: [1, 2, 3],
  dates: [
    ["2020-12-12", "2020-12-19"],
    ["2020-12-13", "2020-12-25"],
    ["2020-12-05", "2020-12-20"],
    ["2020-12-15", "2020-12-17"]
  ]
}];
```

---

Input **exemple B** :

```js
const errors = [
  {
    lines: [1, 2],
    dates: [["2020-12-12", "2020-12-19"], ["2020-12-04", "2020-12-25"]]
  },
  {
    lines: [1, 5],
    dates: [["2020-12-12", "2020-12-19"], ["2020-12-05", "2020-12-20"]]
  },
  {
    lines: [2, 5],
    dates: [["2020-12-04", "2020-12-25"], ["2020-12-05", "2020-12-20"]]
  },
  {
    lines: [3, 4],
    dates: [["2020-10-19", "2020-10-25"], ["2020-10-24", "2020-10-27"]]
  },
  {
    lines: [4, 3],
    dates: [["2020-10-24", "2020-10-27"], ["2020-10-19", "2020-10-25"]]
  },
  {
    lines: [5, 2],
    dates: [["2020-12-05", "2020-12-20"], ["2020-12-04", "2020-12-25"]]
  }
];
```

Output **example B** :

```js
const expected = [
  {
    lines: [1, 2, 5],
    dates: [
      ["2020-12-12", "2020-12-19"],
      ["2020-12-04", "2020-12-25"],
      ["2020-12-05", "2020-12-20"]
    ]
  },
  {
    lines: [3, 4],
    dates: [
      ["2020-10-19", "2020-10-25"],
      ["2020-10-24", "2020-10-27"]
  ]
  }
];
```

I created a sandbox to achieve this :
https://codesandbox.io/s/lodash-sandbox-zsr9r

There is three examples, the third doesn't works.

My current implementation :

```js
const sanatizeErrors = errors.reduce((acc, currentError, i) => {
  const nextError = errors[i + 1]
  const hasOnlySingleError = errors.length === 1

  // The following const is not enough "strong" and it doesn't handle all cases
  const hasCommonErrorWithNextLine =
    nextError && _.includes(nextError.lines, currentError.lines[0])

  if (hasOnlySingleError) {
    return [{
      lines: currentError.lines,
      dates: currentError.dates
    }]
  }

  if (hasCommonErrorWithNextLine) {
    return [
      ...acc,
      {
        lines: _.uniq([
          ...currentError.lines,
          ...nextError.lines
        ]),
        dates: _.uniqWith(
          [
            ...currentError.dates,
            ...nextError.dates
        ], _.isEqual)
      }
    ]
  }

  return acc
}, [])
```

**This final array is used to handle dynamic dates ranges overlaps.**

Any highlight is appreciate =)

Comment: Which step are you having trouble with?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev you can see here https://codesandbox.io/s/lodash-sandbox-zsr9r 
The output array includes two entities vs expected one (for the example C). I suppose that my logic to combine "common" numbers is not enough "flexible".

Comment: Also please post your code here

Comment: done. Thank's for your help

Comment: I'd wager this line is at fault: `_.includes(nextError.lines, currentError.lines[0])`. You're only checking for the first "line" element, while you ought to be checking for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as conditions are quite complex and data structure is also complex - code is quite messy. WIll be glad to check other ideas. I've added comments into snippet to explain the logic. If you have any questions - you are welcome

```js
const errors = [
  {
    lines: [1, 2],
    dates: [["2020-12-12", "2020-12-19"], ["2020-12-04", "2020-12-25"]]
  },
  {
    lines: [1, 5],
    dates: [["2020-12-12", "2020-12-19"], ["2020-12-05", "2020-12-20"]]
  },
  {
    lines: [2, 5],
    dates: [["2020-12-04", "2020-12-25"], ["2020-12-05", "2020-12-20"]]
  },
  {
    lines: [3, 4],
    dates: [["2020-10-19", "2020-10-25"], ["2020-10-24", "2020-10-27"]]
  },
  {
    lines: [4, 3],
    dates: [["2020-10-24", "2020-10-27"], ["2020-10-19", "2020-10-25"]]
  },
  {
    lines: [5, 2],
    dates: [["2020-12-05", "2020-12-20"], ["2020-12-04", "2020-12-25"]]
  }
];

let output = errors.reduce((acc,rec) => {
  let i;
  //iterate through elements of accumulator to check where to merge
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {    
  let current = acc[i]
  // if there are duplicates
  if(current.lines.map(it => rec.lines.indexOf(it) > -1).some(it => it))
    {
      // combine and merge (remove duplicates) arrays of lines   
      acc[i].lines = (acc[i].lines.concat(rec.lines)).filter((it, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(it) === i)
      // combine and merge (remove duplicates) arrays of dates. In filter complex check to find lastPosition of elements. IndexOf wont't work when arrays are compared (as works for lines)
      acc[i].dates = (acc[i].dates.concat(rec.dates)).filter((it, i, arr) => {
  const lastPosition = arr.reduce((acc,rec, idx) => rec[0] === it[0] && rec[1] === it[1] ? idx: acc, 0)
  return i === lastPosition
})
    // if place for merge has been found - finish
    return acc
  }  
  }
    // if there is no place for merge  - add new group
   return [...acc, rec]
  
  },[])


    console.log('result', output);
```